# What disease causes a dog to lose their vision seemingly over night?

Tags: dogs, health, diseases, vision, eye-disease

My dog's eyes have suddenly gone cloudy, and I would have noticed that long before now. It wasn't until my dog's vision was gone that I noticed any changes in her eyes.

She couldn't make it back on the bed at night and I'd find her on the floor in the morning. I thought was she was weak at first - but now, three days later, I know she couldn't find the bed.

I had to clean her eyes a few times because of a slight discharge. I plan to take her to the vet, just waiting on cash flow. She is seven years old.

I assume that my dog lost her vision overnight, which leads me to my question: **what disease causes a dog to lose their vision overnight?**

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very hard to understand because of bad english. Are her eyes cloudy or not? (Depending on your language, some translators have a tendency to change the meaning...) Could you please [edit] your question and make the meaning clear? Please use very short and simple sentences. (It doesn't matter if english is not your native language or you're dyslexic, we won't judge you. We just want to help you, but we need to understand the facts to do that.)

Comment: @Elmy Just edited - a) does it look better and b) does it look like it is still aligned with the author's original question?

Comment: @Nai54 a) it does look better b) if I knew I would have edited it myself ;). I was honestly confused by the original question because it seemed to contradict itself.